# Persistence with JPA says entity is not present in descriptor

Tags: java, eclipse, postgresql, jpa, persistence

we have encountered a problem while trying to implement a ladder-game application with a database. We have an entity named 'Spill' that has a ManyToOne relation to another entity named 'Brett'.

But when persistence tries to map the entities to the database it doesn't seem to find them.

```
Exception [EclipseLink-93] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.0.v20150309-bf26070): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: The table [brett] is not present in this descriptor.
Descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(no.hib.dat101.entities.Spill --> [DatabaseTable(stigespill.spill)])

Exception [EclipseLink-41] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.0.v20150309-bf26070): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: A non-read-only mapping must be defined for the sequence number field.
Descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(no.hib.dat101.entities.Spill --> [DatabaseTable(stigespill.spill)])
```

They are both definetely in the persistence.xml file, and the program seems to connect to the database just fine. We have explicitly given the name and schema name:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="spill",schema = "stigespill")
```

in both classes.

Spill:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="spill",schema = "stigespill")
public class Spill {

  // FELTVARIABLER
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Integer spillid;

  private Integer ferdig;
  private Timestamp dato;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "spill" , cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private List<Spiller> spillere; // TODO Skiftet fra Queue til ArrayList

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "spill" , cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private List<Trekk> trekklog;

  @ManyToOne( cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinColumn(name = "brett", referencedColumnName="brettid", insertable = false, updatable = false)
  private Brett brett;
}
```

Brett:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "brett", schema = "stigespill")
public class Brett {

  // FELTVARIABLER
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Integer brettid;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "brett", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private List<Rute> ruter;
}
```

We have been searching the web and tried to figure this out for the last few hours, but we can't find a solution.

Full console log:

```
[EL Info]: server: 2016-04-26 15:58:15.551--ServerSession(1348949648)--Detected server platform: org.eclipse.persistence.platform.server.NoServerPlatform.
[EL Warning]: metadata: 2016-04-26 15:58:15.876--ServerSession(1348949648)--The reference column name [spillid] mapped on the element [field spill] does not correspond to a valid id or basic field/column on the mapping reference. Will use referenced column name as provided.
[EL Info]: server: 2016-04-26 15:58:15.951--ServerSession(1348949648)--Detected server platform: org.eclipse.persistence.platform.server.NoServerPlatform.
[EL Info]: 2016-04-26 15:58:16.63--ServerSession(1348949648)--EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.0.v20150309-bf26070
[EL Severe]: 2016-04-26 15:58:17.084--ServerSession(1348949648)--Exception [EclipseLink-0] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.0.v20150309-bf26070): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.IntegrityException
```

### Descriptor Exceptions:

Exception [EclipseLink-93] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.0.v20150309-bf26070): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: The table [brett] is not present in this descriptor.
Descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(no.hib.dat101.entities.Spill --> [DatabaseTable(stigespill.spill)])

Exception [EclipseLink-41] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.0.v20150309-bf26070): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: A non-read-only mapping must be defined for the sequence number field.
Descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(no.hib.dat101.entities.Spill --> [DatabaseTable(stigespill.spill)])

### Runtime Exceptions:

[EL Info]: connection: 2016-04-26 15:58:17.087--ServerSession(1348949648)--/file:/Users/../Stigespill/bin/_eclipselink logout successful
[EL Severe]: ejb: 2016-04-26 15:58:17.091--ServerSession(1348949648)--Exception [EclipseLink-0] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.0.v20150309-bf26070): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.IntegrityException

### Descriptor Exceptions:

Exception [EclipseLink-93] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.0.v20150309-bf26070): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: The table [brett] is not present in this descriptor.
Descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(no.hib.dat101.entities.Spill --> [DatabaseTable(stigespill.spill)])

Exception [EclipseLink-41] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.0.v20150309-bf26070): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: A non-read-only mapping must be defined for the sequence number field.
Descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(no.hib.dat101.entities.Spill --> [DatabaseTable(stigespill.spill)])

### Runtime Exceptions:

Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-28019] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.0.v20150309-bf26070): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Deployment of PersistenceUnit [eclipselink] failed. Close all factories for this PersistenceUnit.
Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-0] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.0.v20150309-bf26070): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.IntegrityException

### Descriptor Exceptions:

Exception [EclipseLink-93] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.0.v20150309-bf26070): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: The table [brett] is not present in this descriptor.
Descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(no.hib.dat101.entities.Spill --> [DatabaseTable(stigespill.spill)])

Exception [EclipseLink-41] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.0.v20150309-bf26070): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: A non-read-only mapping must be defined for the sequence number field.
Descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(no.hib.dat101.entities.Spill --> [DatabaseTable(stigespill.spill)])

### Runtime Exceptions:

```
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.createDeployFailedPersistenceException(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:866)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:806)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.getAbstractSession(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:205)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:305)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:337)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:303)
at no.hib.dat101.database.Emh.slettAlt(Emh.java:137)
at no.hib.dat101.main.Main_Tekst.main(Main_Tekst.java:12)
```

Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-28019] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.0.v20150309-bf26070): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Deployment of PersistenceUnit [eclipselink] failed. Close all factories for this PersistenceUnit.
Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-0] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.0.v20150309-bf26070): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.IntegrityException

### Descriptor Exceptions:

Exception [EclipseLink-93] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.0.v20150309-bf26070): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: The table [brett] is not present in this descriptor.
Descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(no.hib.dat101.entities.Spill --> [DatabaseTable(stigespill.spill)])

Exception [EclipseLink-41] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.0.v20150309-bf26070): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: A non-read-only mapping must be defined for the sequence number field.
Descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(no.hib.dat101.entities.Spill --> [DatabaseTable(stigespill.spill)])

### Runtime Exceptions:

```
at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException.deployFailed(EntityManagerSetupException.java:239)
... 8 more
```

Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-0] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.0.v20150309-bf26070): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.IntegrityException

### Descriptor Exceptions:

Exception [EclipseLink-93] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.0.v20150309-bf26070): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: The table [brett] is not present in this descriptor.
Descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(no.hib.dat101.entities.Spill --> [DatabaseTable(stigespill.spill)])

Exception [EclipseLink-41] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.0.v20150309-bf26070): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: A non-read-only mapping must be defined for the sequence number field.
Descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(no.hib.dat101.entities.Spill --> [DatabaseTable(stigespill.spill)])

### Runtime Exceptions:

`at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.initializeDescriptors(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:701)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.initializeDescriptors(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:637)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.initializeDescriptors(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:568)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.postConnectDatasource(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:804)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.loginAndDetectDatasource(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:748)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryProvider.login(EntityManagerFactoryProvider.java:253)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:728)
... 6 more<code>`

Answer (score 0):

In one case, in order to get @Table to work properly, I had to add `catalog` as well. Also, I had to name the table in `@Entity`. Try:

```
@Entity(name="spill")
@Table(name="spill",schema = "stigespill", catalog="public")
```

etc.